# Firebase authentication error googleUser.getAuthResponse is not a function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to Authenticate Using Google Sign-In with JavaScript in my react native app but I am getting the error in my onSignIn() function:

"googleUser.getAuthResponse is not a function"

I am not sure whats causeing this or why I seem to not be obtaining the correct credentials, can someone explain how to remove this error.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import firebase from "firebase";

import {
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithCredential,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  getAuthResponse,
} from "firebase/auth";

import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";

class LoginScreen extends Component {
     isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser) {
       if (firebaseUser) {
         var providerData = firebaseUser.providerData;
         for (var i = 0; i < providerData.length; i++) {
           if (
             providerData[i].providerId ===
               firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID &&
             providerData[i].uid === googleUser.getBasicProfile().getId()
           ) {
            
             return true;
           }
         }
       }
       return false;
     }
```

```
  onSignIn(googleUser) {
    console.log("Google Auth Response", googleUser);
    // We need to register an Observer on Firebase Auth to make sure auth is initialized.
    let unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
      unsubscribe();
      // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
      if (!this.isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
        // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
        const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
         
        );
        console.log("Credential", credential);
        // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithCredential(credential)
        
          .catch((error) => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            let errorCode = error.code;
            let errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            let email = error.email;
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            let credential = error.credential;
            console.log(errorCode, errorMessage, email);
          });
        console.log("WORKED");
      } else {
        console.log("User already signed-in Firebase.");
      }
    });
  }
```

```
  signInWithGoogleAsync = async () => {
    const result = await Google.logInAsync({
      androidClientId: `ANDROID CLIENT ID`,
      iosClientId: `IOS CLIENT ID`,
      scopes: [
        "profile",
        "email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
      ],
    });

    if (result.type === "success") {
      //console.log("Restult ", result);
      this.onSignIn(result);
      return result.accessToken;
    } else {
      return { cancelled: true };
    }
  };
```

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          title="Sign In With Google"
          onPress={() => this.signInWithGoogleAsync()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google/#loginasync), if you want the user, you should use result.user.
Anyway, I see you're using the result just for the token, so you should be ok just changing your code to this:

```
    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      googleUser.idToken
    );
```

since the token is already in the result object.

Comment: when I use googleUser.idToken tho i receive the error "Invalid Idp Response: the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application." ....is it ok to use the idToken to authenticate in this instance because im still not seeing the user logged into my firebase console.